# how to parse datetime.datetime(,,,tzinfo) to spark dataframe

Tags: pyspark

I have following json

```
{'client_partition_id': 2, 'client_id': 'd7d3e26f-d105-4816-825d-d5858b9cf0d1', 'ingestion_timestamp': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 10, 4, 3, 19, 654977, tzinfo=<UTC>)}
```

its in ndjson file

trying to read in `spark spark.read.json()` but getting error parse in pyspark to parse datetime.
please help me to resolve it.

Comment: are you sure that is a standard json format as it looks like it has Python datetime entry?

Comment: reading more about this `ndjson` format, might not be supported by `spark.read.json`, but you could use something like `wholeTextFiles`

Comment: yeah I got it corrected, thanks